# Rails Https redirect to http

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have hosted my website http://www.example.com, and it works fine.
when I try to access it by https://www.example.com, my browser says it is unable to connect?

Is this normal? (Is it a DNS issue or a rails app)

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't a Rails issue, but it's hard to say without more information. The most likely explanation is that your server probably isn't configured to have port 443 open, which is the default port for `https` connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Amazon EC2, you'll need to manually open port 443 in the EC2 security group configuration.